# Remmina won't start

Tags: 22.04, remote-desktop, remmina

I use the Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
After system update when I try to run Remmina there are no errors or other messages.
Remmina launch example:

```
none@none:~$ remmina
none@none:~$
```

I tried reinstall Remmina and find log-file to analyzing, but I couldn't find any information on how to find the log.
Please tell me how to find the log, if it exists, or how to analyze the problem or how to fix the problem
Thank you in advance

p.s. The name none@none is used for security purposes.